# Python: How to use First Class Object Constructor value In another Object

Tags: python

```
class MyClass(Object):

    def __init__(self, x=None):
        if x:
            self.x = x
    def do_something(self):
        print self.x
```

Now I have two objects

`my_class1 = MyClass(x)`

`my_class2 = MyClass()`

I want to use x when this my_class2 object is called

As other languages Support static variable like java,c++ etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign it as property to the class:

```py
>>> class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, x=None):
        if x is not None:
            self.__class__.x = x
    def do_something(self):
        print self.x  # or self.__class__.x, to avoid getting instance property

>>> my_class1 = MyClass('aaa')
>>> my_class2 = MyClass()
>>> my_class2.do_something()
aaa
```

Answer (score 3):

There are no static variables in Python, but you can use the class variables for that. Here is an example:

```
class MyClass(object):
    x = 0

    def __init__(self, x=None):
        if x:
            MyClass.x = x

    def do_something(self):
        print "x:", self.x

c1 = MyClass()
c1.do_something()
>> x: 0

c2 = MyClass(10)
c2.do_something()
>> x: 10

c3 = MyClass()
c3.do_something()
>> x: 10
```

When you call `self.x` - it looks first for instance-level variable, instantiated as `self.x`, and if not found - then looks for `Class.x`. So you can define it on class level, but override it on instance level.

A widely-used example is to use a default class variable with possible override into instance:

```
class MyClass(object):
    x = 0

    def __init__(self, x=None):
        self.x = x or MyClass.x

    def do_something(self):
        print "x:", self.x

c1 = MyClass()
c1.do_something()
>> x: 0

c2 = MyClass(10)
c2.do_something()
>> x: 10

c3 = MyClass()
c3.do_something()
>> x: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. You can use a class attribute instead:

```
class Klass:
   Attr = 'test'

# access it (readonly) through the class instances:
x = Klass()
y = Klass()
x.Attr
y.Attr
```

[Read more](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html) about Python classes.

Comment: But I need to set value of x at run time. is there any other way to  do this?

Comment: @ChZeeshan: Yes, you can assign it to the class, not instance.